# Should I re call an API function after the function fails and I refresh my access token in c#?

Tags: c#, winforms

Sorry if the the title is a little confusing, I have a function that connects to an API when my app starts:

```
private async void connectFunction()
{   
    try 
    {
        result = await myAPICall();
        // do a lot of stuff with the data here
    
    }
    catch (System.ArgumentNullException) // this is only throne when my api access token has expired
    {
        RefreshTokens();
        connectFunction(); //this is what I'm concerned about
    }



}
```

right now all this works great but I don't known what to do next, my access token has been updated and now I need to call the same function again, but I'm concerned that if I call it in the catch block something could go wrong and my app gets stuck in a loop, any advice?

Comment: You should try to have a way of knowing "that your token expires soon". Usually JWT tokens have an expiry timestamp and you can refresh your token *before* errors happen.

Comment: How would I keep a timer going if my app is closed?

Comment: Refresh tokens have an expiry timestamp (a concrete date and time), not a timerange. You could either store the token somewhere (dangerous!) - or always try to fetch a new one when your appliance boots, at least once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to retry once, there's no need for a loop (or recursion):

```
private async void connectFunction()
{   
    MyResultType result;

    try 
    {
        result = await myAPICall();
    }
    catch (System.ArgumentNullException) // this is only throne when my api access token has expired
    {
        RefreshTokens();

        // If this fails, the exception is not caught here, which
        // is a good thing. We know that the token can't be the cause
        // because we just refreshed it, so we *want* this error to
        // bubble up to our generic UI exception handler.
        result = await myAPICall(); 
    }

    // do a lot of stuff with the data here
}
```